# XPath find descendant where ancestor doesn't have specific class

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Trying to create a XPath to find input elements with a specific label on my website. However I want it to not be found if its ancestor is a specific div.

Assume we got the following HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="abc">   
        <div>
            //some other elements
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Name</h2>
            <input></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>   
        <div>
            //some other elements
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Name</h2>
            <input></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only want to find the name input in the div that does not have the surrounding `div` "abc".

I have this that only finds the name input if it's in the the `abc` wrapper but can't make it find the other way around:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'content')]//div[contains(@class, 'abc')]//descendant::h2[.='Name']/following-sibling::input
```

I thought I could use a `not()` function around the `contains(abc)` like so:

```
[not(contains(@class, 'abc'))]
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath will select all `h2` elements whose string value equals `"Name"` and that is not a descendent of a `div` with of `class = 'abc'`:

```
//h2[.='Name' and not(ancestor::div/@class = 'abc')]
```

Comment: Thnaks man it worked, I just have a question regarding this part ´div/@class = 'abc'´ am I understanding this wrong or does that not mean a div with a child that has the class 'abc' instead of the div itself?

Comment: No, `not(ancestor::div/@class = 'abc')` returns true when there are no ancestor `div` elements with `class` attributes equal to `abc`.   It could also be written as `not(ancestor::div[@class = 'abc'])`.